How to correctly route the packets through host and namespaces?
I am trying to route the packets from Client [Host], through namespaces [Demo0 -> Demo1], to Server [Host]. The packets should be routed to tun device 10.0.3.2, from where the black-box process occurs and forwards the data to tun device 10.0.3.1.
The issue is that after applying ip route commands I have managed to get the ICMP request to the Server, but not the reply. For testing I am using ping 10.0.1.2 -I client-eth1 and tcpdump -i any -n -vvv icmp
Visual representation of the setup: https://imgur.com/a/5zIHTE3
I've tried:

enabling ip forwarding in both namespaces and host
making sure no firewall rules interfere with pings
tweaking rp_filters to route the reply using another route
introducing rt_tables and ip rule to try to separate host client and server

Host: ip route show
default via 192.168.100.1 dev wlp0s20f3 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.0.1.0/24 dev server-eth2 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.2 
10.0.1.2 via 10.0.2.1 dev client-eth1 
10.0.2.0/24 dev client-eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.2 
10.0.2.2 via 10.0.1.1 dev server-eth2 


Demo0: ip route show
10.0.0.0/24 dev demo0-eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1 
10.0.1.0/24 via 10.0.3.2 dev tun 
10.0.2.0/24 dev demo0-eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.1 
10.0.2.2 via 10.0.2.1 dev demo0-eth1 
10.0.3.0/24 dev tun proto kernel scope link src 10.0.3.2 


Demo1: ip route show
10.0.0.0/24 dev demo1-eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.2 
10.0.1.0/24 dev demo1-eth2 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.1 
10.0.2.0/24 via 10.0.3.1 dev tun 
10.0.3.0/24 dev tun proto kernel scope link src 10.0.3.1 


I suspect the issue lies in both client and server being on the host and causing issues with routing.I made 2 tables: client and server, and adding the rule:
ip rule add from 10.0.2.2 to 10.0.1.2 lookup client
ip rule add from 10.0.1.2 to 10.0.2.2 lookup server


server table:
ip route add 10.0.2.2 via 10.0.1.1 dev server-eth2
client table:
ip route add 10.0.1.2 via 10.0.2.1 dev client-eth1
Even with the rule in place, the ping state that the Host is Unreachable.
What rules and routes should I change in order for this setup to work?

This is going to be difficult (if  not impossible) to set up if both your origin and destination addresses are on the host. Move your endpoints out of the global network namespace and into their own dedicated namespaces and things will be much simpler.

It worked immediately when I put the server in its own namespace. I tried evading that because that makes debugging and testing more abstract in regards to the error handling and general info.
